# Read a text file and find if a line end on a specific word?

Tags: python

I read i text file line by line and want to find out if a line ends on a specifik word.

My code looks lika this, but result always get false

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import wget

with open("data.txt","r") as f:
    text = f.readlines()

for line in text:
    print line
    result = line.endswith("jpg")
    print(result)
```

And the text file like this:

```
file1.jpg
file2.jpg
file3.png
file4.html
```

Comment: `line.endswith("jpg")` cannot be true because of newline.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html),

> f.readline() reads a single line from the file; a newline character (\n) is left at the end of the string, and is only omitted on the last line of the file if the file doesn’t end in a newline

So really all your lines end with a hidden character after the text that's displayed. You can either include this in your check or find a way to strip it before running your check

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `f.readlines()` adds a new line `\n` in the end of the string.
If you try to `print (text)` you will get the following output that demonstrates this behaviour:

```
['file1.jpg\n', 'file2.jpg\n', 'file3.png\n', 'file4.html']
```

You can use `rstrip('\n')` to remove newlines from the string:

```
import os

with open("data.txt","r") as f:
    text = f.readlines()

for line in text:
    print (line.rstrip('\n'))
    result = line.rstrip('\n').endswith(".jpg")
    print(result)
```

which now gives the correct output:

```
file1.jpg
True
file2.jpg
True
file3.png
False
file4.html
False
```

Comment: Work great! Big thanks!